# Measure of a ray

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider $E_n = [n, \infty)$. What is than the limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(E_n)$$
Is it $0$ or $\infty$?
On one hand, $\forall n: \mu({E_n}) = \infty$.
On the other hand, consider $x \in \mathbb{R}$, for each $x$ there exist N such that $x \notin E_n \; \forall n \geq N$.

Comment: Just a question, but if the result of a function goes to infinity for all input variables, how would it be possible that the limit does not go to infinity?

Comment: Neither $0$ nor $\infty$. The term is not well defined, since you have a sequence of infinities.

Comment: Each term is infinite, so if a limit exists, it would have to be $\infty$.

Comment: @freakish Why? The measure of $E_n$ is defined, so sould be the limit.

Comment: @Daniil because then you have an invalid equality $0=\mu(\bigcap E_n)=\lim E_n=\infty$.

Comment: @Dominique  I added the "other hand" argument to the post.  This argument confuses me.

Comment: @freakish but $\lim\mu(E_n) = \mu(\lim(E_n))$ only holds for finite measure sequences. So I should dissagree with you.

Comment: @Daniil indeed. And that's why definining $\lim\infty$ arbitrarily as $\infty$ is confusing and doesn't lead to anything useful. Because now you've detached it from measure completely, its a random definition. So why not $6$ for example?

Comment: @Daniil, freakish is right, this invalidates the "decreasing limit" property of measures. What you have is a sequence in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, so you can add to it a topology but it needs to be well defined, and the limit will be $\infty$. This will have no meaning whatsoever in term of measure theory. It can however be a nice counterexample for the "finite" property.

Comment: @Daniil I clicked enter too quick. But this is a comment not an answer. Also the usual topology on $\mathbb{R_+} \cup \{\infty\}$is given by neighborhoods of $\mathbb{R}$'s topology alongside with the $(a,\infty)$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I still disagree with commentators who state this limit doesn't exist or "is not well defined". The answer is that $lim_{n \to \infty} \mu (E_n) = \infty$, and it's not a random number, it's just a limit of a stationary sequence. The quality mentioned in comments: $\mu(\lim E_n) = \lim \mu (E_n)$ only holds for finite measure sets, as I said, so it doesn't contraidict anything.

To clear things up: I consider space [$-\infty, +\infty$]. I thought it's obvious, since I asked about $+\infty$ sequences limit, but still.

My previous answer was hidden by people who didn't even bother to answer my question, but whatsoever I consider this post as an answer and will mark it so in two days.

Comment: The equality $\mu (\lim E_n) = \lim \mu (E_n)$ holds for finite measure sets but it does not imply the sets have to be finite measure (which is what you said). This answer adds nothing other than "the answer is $\infty$ because I say so". How very mathematical..

Comment: It means this equality has nothing to do with my question. The answer is aclually mathematical (and turned out very based math), because we just taking a limit of a stationary sequence. I don't really see what confuses you. I asked a question because I had some confusion (and arguments in question wasn't discussed at all - now, that's "very mathematical"), then I found answer to MY question - which was indeed mine, and you still have some complait? Disgusting.

Comment: Also I didn't say anything about "the sets have to be finite measure", that's words of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to precisely phrase the setting you are working in, I think you are considering the topological space $[0,\infty]$ with the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology). That is $[0,\infty)\sqcup\{ \infty \}$ with a topology generated by rays $(a,\infty)\sqcup\{\infty\}$ and $(b,\infty)$ or $[0,\infty)$.

Within this space $\mu(E_n)\equiv \infty$ and so  the limit must be $\infty$, as this space is Hausdorff. This is essentially what *julio_es_sui_glance* told you.

Comment: But the question was not about topology nor do I know what it is. In my measure classes we didn't define such word.

Comment: Also I already wrote an answer with exactly the same statement about the limit.

Comment: @Daniil Without this notion, there is not true meaning to the limit you stated. Convergence or divergence is in a space. What does it mean for a sequence of infinities to converge? Without this notion of convergence in $[0,\infty]$, you lack some definition of what is $\lim a_n$ with $a_n\equiv \infty$. In the classical case, $\lim a_n$ is not even defined.

Comment: Well, you said this space is Hausdorff. That's all that matters.

Comment: I generally agree with you, I just don't know anything about topology.

Comment: Just ordinary $R^m$ with $+- \infty$ and convergence of unbounded monotonous sequences.